# Jquery Datatables Moment error invalid date error

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I get the following error in my console log. What am I doing wrong?

```
   p {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: '', _f: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss', _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, …}
_d: Invalid Date {}
_f: "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss"
_i: ""
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: false
_isValid: false
_locale: P
```

`data.planning_deadline` has the following format of date values stored `21-10-2021`

Below code:

```
rowCallback: function ( row, data ) {
                var daysleft = moment(data.planning_deadline, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss');
                console.log(daysleft);
                var now = moment(); 
                
                 if ( daysleft.diff(now, 'days') <= 0 && data.planning_deadline != "" && data.planning_afgehandeld == 0 ){
                 $('td:eq(0)', row).css('background-color', ' rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)');
                 }
```

Comment: What error are you referring to? Does your DataTable work as expected? If not, then in what way is it not working?

Comment: Can you please make a reproducible example? Or at least post your data structure?

Comment: What index is your planning_deadline? Instead of calling `data.planning_deadline`, try calling `data[i]`. `[i]` whatever index planning_deadline falls under

Comment: Datatables work. Only the date parse is not working after i changed the colomn format from 2021-12-01 to 01-12-2021. So i suspect the format is not correct for moment js?

Comment: To be exact. The difference between days are not counted well. When I added the console log on the variable it said that date is invalid

Comment: Suggestion: If you are seeing the error message `Invalid date` when you try to use `moment(data.planning_deadline, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss')`, then that suggests that somewhere in your "planning deadline" source data you have a value which does not fit that format - for example, `12-25-2021`, where the day and month values are the wrong way round. Inspect the source data. Remove all source records except one or two which you _know_ to be OK, then see if the DataTable works correctly. Add more records until you get the error... Repeat...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. As dates in the opposit format in the table was indeed the case ! Thanks yet again !

Comment: Great - glad it is solved. A suggestion for the future:  Providing a [mre] (code and data) can make your question more specific and easier to answer.